# How can I fix "MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15"?

Tags: time-machine

For the last few weeks, I've been getting lots of recurrent `MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15` error messages in `system.log`. How can I diagnose and fix this?

I don't know if it's causing any issues, but it's worrisome, and it's spamming the log file so I'm having trouble diagnosing other problems. Time Machine has also been wonky lately, failing to complete backups to external drives attached to my Time Capsule because it couldn't find the backup disk. (Backups to locally-attached drives work fine.) Maybe related, since `mtmfs` is part of the Time Machine system.

Here's what it looks like, from `system.log` as viewed in Console. There will be a sequence of errors and restart attempts, which then get throttled.

```
Nov 28 15:08:18 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: cannot bind custom tcp socket
Nov 28 15:08:18 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15
Nov 28 15:08:19 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server retrying ...
Nov 28 15:08:19 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: cannot bind custom tcp socket
Nov 28 15:08:19 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15
Nov 28 15:08:21 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server retrying ...
Nov 28 15:08:21 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: cannot bind custom tcp socket
Nov 28 15:08:21 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15
Nov 28 15:08:22 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server retrying ...
Nov 28 15:08:22 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: cannot bind custom tcp socket
Nov 28 15:08:22 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15
Nov 28 15:08:24 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server retrying ...
Nov 28 15:08:24 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: cannot bind custom tcp socket
Nov 28 15:08:24 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of error 15
Nov 28 15:08:25 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server retrying ...
Nov 28 15:08:25 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed to start because of too many retries
Nov 28 15:08:25 eilonwy.local mtmfs[379]: MTM fs Mount server failed, last error 15
Nov 28 15:08:25 eilonwy com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mtmfs[379]): Exited with code: 99
Nov 28 15:08:25 eilonwy com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mtmfs): Throttling respawn: Will start in 3 seconds
```

This repeats constantly, ending up with about 150,000 `mtmfs` error messages in `system.log` every day.

This is on OS X 10.8.5 on a Mid 2012 Retina MacBook Pro. `eilonwy` is the hostname of my machine.

I've looked through what little doco on `mtmfs` I've found through `man` and Google, and while it tells how to start and stop it, I've found no info on what `error 15` means, what "custom tcp socket" it might be trying to bind to and how to fix, and what the consequences of `mtmfs` not running are.

I contacted Apple support and they suggested doing a "Repair Permissions" from Disk Utility, which I did and it didn't fix the problem, and then reinstalling OS X, which is a little aggressive (and Windows-y) for my taste.

Can anyone help me fix this, or point at some resources to help diagnose it?

Comment: Any success Andrew (or anyone else) in fixing this? I've got the same error repeating constantly.

Comment: I eventually gave up, erased my drive, and did a fresh re-install of OS X 10.9. Error went away. (Just upgrading to 10.9 did not fix it.)

Comment: @rtaustin - Can you give bmike's answer a try and let us know if it works for you?

Comment: @rtaustin: check BMourelo's new answer. Think he nailed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and was due to errors in the localhost's IPv4 address in /etc/hosts. The daemon of mtmfs listening on localhost.

Check that this is the first line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Also you can test: (depends on the firewall options)

```
$ ping localhost
```

Then turn off local Time Machine snapshots and trigger automatic cleanup of accumulated local snapshot data :

```
$ sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

Reboot the mac, and turn on local Time Machine snapshots:

```
$ sudo tmutil enablelocal
```

And it works without errors.

```
[system.log] mtmfs[40]: mount succeeded for /Volumes/MobileBackups
```

Comment: Bingo! I pulled my old `/etc/hosts` from the time of the issue off backups, and indeed its `127.0.0.1` localhost entry was commented out and replaced by a normal `192.168.0.xxx` IP address. I can reproduce the exact symptoms by messing up `/etc/hosts` again, giving localhost an incorrect IP. (No idea why it got changed in the first place.) Your fix works. Thanks!

Comment: Ditto bingo! I had 172.0.0.2 in my hosts file and it was defaulting to it. Removed. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had miserable luck interacting with mtmfs and fixing things when they go amiss. I do have good success in cleaning out the mobile store and starting the mobile backup portion clean.

Make a time machine backup with your normal destination drive mounted, then disable - let the system clean up the on-disk cache space and then re-enable the local snapshot store. You do lose any backup intervals that are not on the actual destination, but you also get a working set. Lastly, I would run `tmdiagnose` to capture the failure before you clean up just in case it reappears and you can send both sets of diagnostic logs to Apple for analysis by engineering.

```
sudo -s
tmutil startbackup --rotation --block
tmdiagnose
tmutil disablelocal
sleep 30
tmutil enablelocal
exit
```

At this point, you'll want to test a backup or two and repeat the tmdiagnose if you happen to reproduce the issue:

```
tmutil snapshot
sleep 15
tmutil startbackup --rotation --block
sleep 15
tmutil snapshot
```

Comment: +1 Thanks bmike! I didn't know about `tmdiagnose`; that looks helpful. I had tried `tmutil` `disablelocal`/`enablelocal`, but it didn't fix it. Maybe I didn't wait long enough between them? Anyway, I gave up and reformatted, so I can't test this for reproducibility. Don't know what the etiquette is wrt Accepting when the original situation is gone...

Comment: @AndrewJanke The best etiquette is to select some answer if the problem can no longer be reproduced. That spurs others to either edit the question to show how to reproduce it or ask a new question. You are encouraged to answer it yourself if for whatever reason selecting one of the existing answers. So, unless you want to tick mine as answering, go ahead and self-answer.